# HttpContext.Error vs HttpContext.Server.GetLastError()

Tags: asp.net

Are there any practical differences between these two ways of getting an exception for the current asp.net request?

MSDN says HttpContent.Error returns the FIRST error while GetLastError() is evidently the last error, but I can't seem to tell any difference in use.

Which one is the cannon method for error logging?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're the same:

[`HttpContext.Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.error.aspx) returns the first error.

[`HttpContext.Server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.server.aspx) returns an instance of the `HttpServerUtility` class, which provides convenience wrappers for `HttpContext`, including

[`HttpContext.Server.GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx), which returns `HttpContext.Error` (verified using Reflector).

Comment: Additionally GetLastError is checking firstly for the error on the HttpContext, and then the HttpApplication.. this is because a HttpServerUtility can be created with a HttpApplication instead of a HttpContext.. -- overall, it should make no difference, but stick to GetLastError probably.

Comment: @meandmycode: while HttpServerUtility is able to retrieve the error from HttpApplication, the instance returned from HttpContext does not. (HttpApplication.Server will give you one that does)

Comment: agree with @Shog9: the source code of HttpApplication.Error shows that it loads error from HttpContext, but if context is not available, it returns last application error (for example, initialized through RaiseErrorWithoutContext)