# When does HttpContext.AllErrors contain more than one exception?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, httpcontext

In an ASP.NET application typical error handling code involves [some variation of `GetLastError()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740482/httpcontext-error-vs-httpcontext-server-getlasterror), however there's also [`HttpContext.AllErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.allerrors(v=vs.110).aspx) collection of which the `GetLastError()` method only retrieves the first one. What are the scenarios where the `AllErrors` collection might contain more than 1 exception? I cannot think of anything, but obviously it's there for a purpose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET Framework supports a different model where a request can encounter multiple errors, all of which can be reported without stopping request processing, allowing for more nuanced and useful information to be presented to the user.

```
namespace ErrorHandling
{
    // sample class adding errors to HttpContext
    public partial class SumControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                int? first = GetIntValue("first");
                int? second = GetIntValue("second");
                if (first.HasValue && second.HasValue)
                {
                    //result.InnerText = (first.Value + second.Value).ToString();
                    //resultPlaceholder.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Context.AddError(new Exception("Cannot perform calculation"));
                }
            }
        }

        private int? GetIntValue(string name)
        {
            int value;
            if (Request[name] == null)
            {
                Context.AddError(new ArgumentNullException(name));
                return null;
            }
            else if (!int.TryParse(Request[name], out value))
            {
                Context.AddError(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name));
                return null;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
// intercepting the errors
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.AllErrors != null && Context.AllErrors.Length > 1)
        {
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            Server.Execute("/MultipleErrors.aspx");
            Context.ClearError();
        }
    }
}
// MultipleErrors code behind
public partial class MultipleErrors : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetErrorMessages()
    {
        return Context.AllErrors.Select(e => e.Message);
    }
}
```

The answer is heavily referencing pro asp.net 4.5 from appress

Comment: Hmm, but that will then only appear in my own code (and if I don't do it, I don't need to worry about it). ASP.NET itself doesn't do this?

Comment: that explain things further i think: notice that we call the HttpContext.ClearError method after we have generated our error page. Calling the
AddError method doesn’t trigger the Error event, but it does trigger the built-in ASP.NET error handling support that
we configured in the Web.config file earlier in the chapter. If we don’t call ClearError, then our multi-error page will
be replaced with whatever the Web.config file specifies.

Comment: Wouldn't that rather go in `ModelState`?

Comment: so you can think of the above as a manually written exception driven error page, without asp.net/IIS intervention as per we are clearing after our self by calling Context.ClearError();

Comment: Ermm... check my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525342/can-application-endrequest-be-used-instead-of-application-error