# Can Application_EndRequest be used instead of Application_Error?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

I want to handle all uncaught exceptions in my ASP.NET application. I want to display a custom UI to the user, but NOT redirect them (so the URL would be the original URL which produced the exception). I also have [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which is configured by the end-user (well, end-administrator really, but not me). Elmah attaches a handler to the `Application.Error` event and does it's logging there.

I now have two possible places to handle the error and generate the output `Application_Error` and `Application_EndRequest`. The logical place would be `Application_Error`, but that has two problems:

1. If I don't remove the exception with `ClearError()`, ASP.NET will replace my output with it's own default output.
2. But if I do remove it with `ClearError()`, then ELMAH might not get the exception because the event handler execution order is undefined.

I checked that the error still persists in `Application_EndRequest` so I could do it there, but that feels kinda.... wrong. Can I get into trouble by doing this?

Comment: elmah will be your last resort, helping you in identifying unplanned crashed in certain scenarios, you have a logging system in place like log4net right?

Comment: @sarepta - ELMAH will be my log system for uncaught exceptions. Why have two?

Comment: what about caught ones :-) those need logging too

Comment: @sarepta - Oh, that. Yes, I'll have that too, and it will be funneled to Elmah as well.